# Push notification stop working on my live app

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have used push notification in one of my  app which is live on appstore and google play market both. It was working fine before some days on both type of devices iPhone and android. But now its working only on android devices . On iPhone Devices push notification is not receiving. We can still send from iPhone to andriod but not able to receive on iPhone.Its working on android to android too.

Just Want to know that does this happen due to any of recent release of ios versions or anything bad happend on server ? Web services code is in Ruby on rails. Please suggest what should I check to fix the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: What is the server response? Are the devices registering successfully and getting tokens?

Comment: Yes, devices registering and we checked in DB there is token for each devices.

Comment: What is the response from the server? Are you polling for removed devices as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your APN certificate hasn't expired (you can check it in the Apple provisioning portal).

Comment: It means if we have to renew certificates, make new .pem file and upload to server every year while your app is live.

Comment: Is that a question? If it is then - yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is not a problem related to your Server or recent release of ios versions. It might be the problem with the certificate as mentioned by Eran. The Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) certificate, lasts for one year and must be renewed annually. You can create a new certificate or renew your older certificate.